# SQLite производительность

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Есть ли разница в скорости получения данных из таблицы SQLite на Android:

Первый вариант:

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select a,b,c from table");
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        arrayList.add(c.getString(0));
    }
```

Второй вариант:

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select a,b,c from table where a = " + i)
        String a = c.getString(0);
        arrayList.add(a);
    }
```

Мне нужен второй способ, но он вызывает у меня сомнения. Если он тратит больше времени, то есть ли другой, более быстрый, но чтобы данные получались последовательно, вместо возвращения целого курсора с данными?

Comment: Может `select a,b,c from table where a between 1 and 10` ?

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант вероятно будет работать гораздо медленнее. Если есть возможность получить все данные одним обращением к БД(1 вариант), т.к. зачем вы намеренно обращаетесь к бд множество раз(2 вариант)?

А вообще просто сравните скорость выполнения первого и второго способа на большом объёме данных.

Меня только смущает в вашем втором варианте i<10.
Первый вариант должен выглядеть видимо так:

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select a,b,c from table where a>=0 and a<10");
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        arrayList.add(c.getString(0));
    }
```

Comment: Это я для примера. Сейчас исправлю. А если сначала получить данные в курсор, а потом распределять их по массивам, это будет быстрее или так же затратно для производительности?

Comment: Ваш вариант не совсем корректен. Перед получением данных из курсора надо вызвать один из методов: ```move(int offset)/moveToFirst()/moveToLast()/moveToNext()moveToPosition(int position)/moveToPrevious()```, и после завершение работы с курсором его надо закрыть.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал проверку `if(c.moveToFirst())`, странно что вы эту команду не вызываете. А в цикле нужно использовать `c.moveToNext()`.

Comment: Код для примера. В реальных условиях я двигаю курсор на первую позицию.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, что использовать - for или do while.

Comment: С while отпечатался, ответ отредактировал